# Margins / Padding on Rotated Text in Table Cells

Tags: html, css, rotation

I have a table with rotated text in the headings.  I borrowed CSS from elsewhere and revised for a rotation of 90 degrees instead of -90 degrees.  There is a wide space before (*i.e.* above) each column of rotated text.  I'd like to get rid of it, and nothing I've tried works.

There is a lot of HTML and a fair amount of CSS, so I've put the whole thing in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SLkfR/.

One line of the rotated text looks like this:
`<td><div class="vertical-text"><div class="vertical-text-inner">InvA</div></div></td>`

The CSS looks like:

```
body {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
table {text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;}
table.uprog {border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse: collapse;  table-layout: fixed;}
table.uprog th {vertical-align: top;  border-right: 1px solid gray;}
.uprog td {text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid gray; }
.uprog td.mal {text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;}
.uprog th {text-align: center; font-weight: bold;}
.vertical-text {
    font-size: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1.2em;
    line-height: 4em;
}
.vertical-text-inner {
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform:  rotate(90deg);
}
```

I know the vertical text is in a TD with `vertical-align: middle;`  Changing that to `top` doesn't make any difference.

The rotation doesn't work at all in Chrome because I haven't put in the necessary -webkit stuff.  The fiddle does work (except for the extra space that I want to get rid of) in FF and IE.  I don't have enough reputation to post multiple links; there's a credit for the borrowed CSS as a comment in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a substantial amount of messing around, I've realized that, although the *text* is rotated, top, left, etc. on the DIV itself are oriented just like always, according to the CSS box model.  So, a negative top margin on the DIV moves the rotated text upward.  The `vertical-align: middle;` of the table-data tag aligns the entire box formed by the DIV.

The CSS now looks like this:

```
.vertical-text {
    font-size: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 1.2em;
    line-height: 4.4em;
    margin-top: -1.3em;   /* THIS is what fixed it! */
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform:  rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(90deg);
}
```

I was able to get rid of the inner , `.vertical-text-inner`.  For reasons I haven't figured out yet, I had to change overflow to visible.

I haven't changed the fiddle in case someone has a more elegant solution.  You can see the result of the above changes in their native habitat here: http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/faculty/rbrow211/tlc/docs.html#uprogtable">http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/faculty/rbrow211/tlc/docs.html#uprogtable.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for:

```
transform-origin: top-left;
```